# React how to return a label message based on if else condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, if-statement

quite a beginner here but I am struggling to get the following to work.
I have an if else condition here that I want the label message to depend on but I am getting an error message
Cannot find name 'message'
What am I doing wrong?
The if else condition is the following:

```
if(devEnv()) {
    const message = useMessageAsString(
      <FormattedMessage
        id="xxxxxx"
        defaultMessage="I've read and accept the <aTerms>Terms of Use</aTerms> and <aPrivacy>Privacy Policy</aPrivacy>"
        values={{
          aTerms: (msg: string) => (
            <a
              rel="noreferrer noopener"
              target="_blank"
              href={URL_TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS_DEV}
            >
              {msg}
            </a>
          ),
          aPrivacy: (msg: string) => (
            <a
              rel="noreferrer noopener"
              target="_blank"
              href={URL_PRIVACY_POLICY}
            >
              {msg}
            </a>
          ),
        }}
      />
    )
  } else {
    const message = useMessageAsString(
      <FormattedMessage
        id="xxxxx"
        defaultMessage="I've read and accept the <aTerms>Terms of Use</aTerms> and <aPrivacy>Privacy Policy</aPrivacy>"
        values={{
          aTerms: (msg: string) => (
            <a
              rel="noreferrer noopener"
              target="_blank"
              href={URL_TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS}
            >
              {msg}
            </a>
          ),
          aPrivacy: (msg: string) => (
            <a
              rel="noreferrer noopener"
              target="_blank"
              href={URL_PRIVACY_POLICY}
            >
              {msg}
            </a>
          ),
        }}
      />
    )
  }
```

And then in the return I want to do this:

```
<CheckBox
                  data-testid={'terms_and_privacy_policy'}
                  checked={formValues.accepted_terms_and_privacy_policy}
                  onChange={() => {
                    if (!isValid) {
                      triggerValidation()
                    }
                    onFormFieldChange(
                      'accepted_terms_and_privacy_policy',
                      !formValues.accepted_terms_and_privacy_policy
                    )
                  }}
                  label={message}
                />
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the variable `message` is only declared within a limited scope. If this code all lives within `render()` then try defining the message before checking the condition as a mutable `var` (or `let`) like this:

```
var message = "";
if (devEnv()) {
  message = useMessageAsString(
  ...
} else {
  message = useMessageAsString(
  ...
}

return (
 ...
 label={message}
)
```

Alternatively you can stick with `const` but use a ternary operator for the assignemnt:

```
const message = devEnv() ? versionA : versionB;
```

If, for some reason, you are using class based components, and the message is defined in another function from `render` then you will need to declare it as a field on the class.

Comment: Hi, thank you Hubert, I got this to work now! Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: No worries. Happy to help!